# Run a Service continuously in the background to watch for the time

Tags: java, android, service

I've a date and time stored in database, I need to continuously monitor the time and date in the background and run a function in the app when that time comes, there can be set of of date and time's, i only know that i need services to do this, but not more than that. can some please tell whether this can be achieved or not? if yes, please suggest me how I can proceed further.Thank u...

Comment: You don't need a Service. Use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to set alarms at the times needed to run whatever component of your app handles your "function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a very developer friendly class for that: [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

So, take the **Date** an **Time** from database, define an alarm event with it, subscribe your app for notifications for that and wait until the event comes to do the job you need to do.

this is how:

```
public class MyAlarm extends IntentService {
    private NotificationManager myAlarmNotificationManager;

    public MyAlarm() {
        super("MyAlarm");
    }


    //this send the notification
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Log.d("MyAlarm", "Preparing to send notification...: " + message);
        myAlarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentText(message);


        alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        myAlarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
        Log.d("MyAlarm", "Notification sent.");
    }


     @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        sendNotification("Do something");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u, I'll try this